# In Linux configuring virtual host and localhost redirecting to the xampp folder

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have problem with vertual host in linux .
Port number is opened and i have write the code in httpd-vhosts.conf file.

**Code:-**

```
<VirtualHost *:8300>
    ServerAdmin "webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com"
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xyz"
    ServerName "localhost:8300"
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**method 2:-**

```
<VirtualHost *:8300> 
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xyz"
    ServerName localhost:8300
    ServerAlias localhost:8300
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xyz">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is this is redirecting to xampp folder.

Comment: I've never seen a servername with a portnumber, nor with quotes. Perhaps try ServerName localhost and remove ServerAlias?

Comment: I have tried with mwthod1,is it ok method1?

Comment: Just to test your configuration you should use the bare minimum first:
<VirtualHost *:8374>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xyz"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

Comment: The problem is probably the use of localhost as the server name, here. the main xampp server is probably set to vhost on localhost and listen on all ports. Make sure that you don't have anything else in the config with a servername of localhost as first defined wins. Or if you do set it only to listen on port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:8300>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/xyz
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog logs/error.log
   CustomLog logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Should work unless you are receiving another error when you access localhost:8300, like permission denied. You'll also need to make sure `Listen 8300` is present in your httpd.conf.

Comment: @User Please give more details. What sort of response are you receiving when you put `localhost:8374` into your browser? Did you restart Apache after making the changes? Did you add the `Listen 8374` directive to your httpd.conf?

Comment: I have added Listen 8374 in  httpd.conf file and restarted the xampp also.

Answer (score 2):

After many trails i have find a answer for this virtual host configuration.

I have done the small mistake, that is i have not enable the virtual host config file in **httpd.conf** file.

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I have enable this one and configured virtual host in **httpd-vhosts.conf** file like

```
<VirtualHost *:8300>
    ServerAdmin "webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com"
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xyz"
    ServerName "localhost:8300"
   ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

After that restarted the xampp server,now it's working fine..

Hope this helps to others.